# LESS Mixins proper way

Tags: css, less

I want to make some LESS function for making border, but something i got wrong

```
.border(@position : left, @color, @size: 1px ){  
    border-@position-width: @size 
    border-@position-color: @color
    border-@position-style: solid;
}
```

Comment: You need to use `@{position}` for property interpolation.

Comment: Never mind mate. Another answer has already been posted. A side note, I would personally recommend using `;` as parameter separator instead of comma.

Comment: Ok, zessx was the first :(

Comment: Thats fine mate. As long as the problem is solved, all is well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use interpolation `@{var}` instead of `@var`, and set a default value for `@color` and add `;` at the end of your lines:

```
.border(@position: left, @color: black, @size: 1px ){  
  border-@{position}-width: @size; 
  border-@{position}-color: @color;
  border-@{position}-style: solid;
}
```

Comment: Win Less does not want to compile it, says parser error

Comment: Just tried with WinLess, no error with this code. Please check that you're compiling the right file, and that you haven't got any other error.